# Postgresql join sub or where sub

Tags: sql, postgresql, conditional-statements, where-clause

My tests give the same run rate. I'm trying to figure out that it's best to use **join** or **subquery**. I understand that much depends on the data, the indexes, and the *DB* itself, but I want to distinguish it so if the records in *t1* are less than *t2* then the **subquery** should be effective, but if on the contrary then **join**.

```
EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT *
FROM safety_policies
WHERE safety_policies.area_id IN (SELECT areas.id
                                  FROM areas
                                    INNER JOIN departments ON areas.department_id = departments.id);


EXPLAIN ANALYSE SELECT safety_policies.*
                FROM safety_policies
                  INNER JOIN areas ON safety_policies.area_id = areas.id
                  INNER JOIN departments ON areas.department_id = departments.id;
```

Comment: it will have two identical results

Comment: Fundamentally, unless there is a SIGNIFICANT performance difference (and there shouldn't be) you should be guided by whichever most accurately reflects your intent. The code readabiity is important and this will be largely informed by the intent in the construction of the query.

Comment: @YaroslavMaluk . . . The two queries may *happen* to produce the same results because of your data, but they are not guaranteed to.  Hence, you should express the query that implements your intent:  do you or do you now want duplicates from `safety_policies` depending on what is in the other two tables.

Comment: I realized why you replied about duplication - no logic would allow me to have duplication. I'm just very confused - I can do it in different ways, but I do not know what's better